# asp.net Thread vs IRegisteredObject for queue polling

Tags: asp.net, multithreading, iis, threadpool, iis-8.5

I have an ASP.NET application where I need to poll the Amazon queue service on a new thread. I know that if I spawn a new thread, ASP.NET has no awareness of it, and may terminate it abruptly if it for whatever reason deems the app pool needs to be recycled, for example changing the web.config.

I tested this by manually recycling the app pool in IIS, however the problem is the thread didnt come back up and start polling after the recycle. Does that mean in production the thread will just stop polling when IIS feels like it?

Perhaps other cases I should be aware of?

So the question is is `Thread` not safe for this type of processing. Or should I use `IRegisteredObject` in which case when should I call `RegisterObject()/UnregisterObject()` in `Application_End` in global.asax or `AppDomain.CurrentDomain.DomainUnload`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Web server is NOT designed for long running or scheduled tasks. As you mentioned the server may choose to shut itself down whenever it feels like to and it will not resume the previous unfinished work, it just aborts it. The best you can do is to use some scheduled visit program which hits your website every x minute to keep it alive and hopefully the server won't kill the thread by then. And then in the begin request event check if the thread is alive, if not restart it. But I would HIGHLY recommend using a windows service to do what you want instead of doing that on a web server.